# Why is Python package Fiona is searching for Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT?

Tags: python, pip, conda, python-wheel, fiona

I installed Python package Fiona. When I try to import it in my application, I get the following error:

> File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 7, in
>
> from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

I used Windows's "Event Viewer" and checked the problem:

> Activation context generation failed for
>   "C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\netcdf.dll". Dependent Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

From this [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6588fbd3-5e94-4053-8496-4d95ee25f45f/question-for-sidebyside-issue-with?forum=vcgeneral) I gather that some module is using a debug library, which it shouldn't. I thought that maybe it's GDAL? How can I detect whether Fiona itself or some dependency of Fiona is doing it?

I tried to uninstall Fiona (and GDAL) and reinstall them.

I can successfully uninstall and install them using:

```
conda uninstall fiona 
conda uninstall gdal
conda install fiona
conda install gdal
```

But the error remains.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got my code working by using the Windows binaries from the following page:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

and installing them with the command:

```
pip install C:\<path>\some_wheel.whl
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I have the same problem and I don't know how to solve it.